# Cant create List of my object type

Tags: java

Im using netbeans to create a java project for school, and in my servlet class Im creating a list:

```
List<Task> myList=new ArrayList<>();
```

to hold my Task objects, but im getting error:

> Type  List does not takes parameters

This is really weird...I'v done this before and never got this error, can someone please explain me what this about?

thanks

Comment: What did you import? Perhaps `java.awt.List`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be importing `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`